# Is it possible to write a macro to generate N enum variants based on a common name?

Tags: macros, rust

I'd like to write a macro with the shape:

```
macro_rules! build {
    ($name:ident, $mask:ty, $end:expr)  => {
        enum $name<K, V {
            //???
        }
    };
}
```

Such that when invoked with:

```
build! {
    Node, u64, 64
}
```

It expands to:

```
enum Node<K, V> {
    Node1(u64, Box<[Node<K, V>; 1]>),
    Node2(u64, Box<[Node<K, V>; 2]>),
    // ...
    Node64(u64, Box<[Node<K, V>; 64]>),
}
```

Is this possible with `macro_rules`?

Comment: Why not use `Box<[T]>` like `struct Node<K, V>(u64, Box<[Node<K, V>]>)` in this case? The data layout seems almost the same except for the maximum length of the array and the order of the fields.

Comment: No, you cannot generate new identifiers (`Node1`, `Node2`, ...) in a macro.